# How to check if referrer is specified

Tags: javascript

I have been stuck on this for over one hour:

```
   if((document.referrer===undefined)){

  if(url_window_location=='http://www.lhttp://livecas.com/sandbox/andbox/'){
      event_google_analytics_referrer=document.referrer.toString(); 
         log("DOCUMENT REFERRER: cookie is set user_details: "+document.referrer);
        eraseCookie('user_details');
         setCookie('user_details',document.referrer,365); 
   }

    if(url_window_location=='hhttp://livecas.com/sandbox/e')
    {   
        eraseCookie('user_details');
        setCookie('landing_page_ref',"FBLND1",365);
        //   log("Cookie is set"); 
    }
 }

 else{

       if(url_window_location=='http://livecas.com/sandbox/'){
            eraseCookie('user_details');
         setCookie('user_details',"Direct",365); 
          log("Direct cookie is set");

          event_google_analytics_referrer="Direct";
      }
 }
```

If document.referrer is set/exists or whatever, i want it to execute the block in the if condition if not I want it the else condition. now it goes to the else condition no matter what

Comment: Can't you just use `if (!document.referrer) { ... }` ?

Comment: please format your d**n code...

Comment: document.referrer won't be undefined, but the empty string, if there is no referrer.

Comment: Currently you are testing if `document.referrer` is explicitly `undefined` try `if(!document.referrer)` to test if it is falsy and then your statement will work correctly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`document.referrer` always exists. It's just that sometimes it's blank (empty string).

Instead of `if( document.referrer === undefined)`, just use `if(!document.referrer)` instead. This will run for all falsy values.

Comment: How do you check if the string ISN'T empty?

Comment: if(!document.referrer) checks if it exits and is not empty.

Comment: `if(document.referrer.length)` true if string is empty.